# How to create a shared secret S from a subset of existing secrets n, such that k out of n secrets can recreate S?

Tags: secret-sharing

In traditional secret sharing schemes, like [Shamir's Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing), first a secret ***S*** is generated. Then it is divided into ***n*** parts, such that a subset ***k*** of the ***n*** parts are sufficient to reconstruct ***S***.

My problem is that I already have ***n*** individual and independent secrets. Is there a way to come up with a shared secret ***S*** from these pre-existing ***n*** secrets, such that a subset ***k*** of the ***n*** parts are sufficient to reconstruct ***S***?

Comment: Questions like this are always difficult. I'm not aware of any way to do it, but I'm also not aware of a proof that no such thing exists. The simple case is when $k=n$, in which case use just use the XOR of the secrets. For $k<n$, my gut feeling is that this is impossible.